# Azure Webjob: Git clone directly to remote

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, libgit2sharp

Im running a Windows-based App Service.

Im running a backup of a fairly large git repo and I'm wanting to clone directly to Azure Blob/File/S3. Cloning locally leads to an out-of-memory exception. I realise that you can mount azure storage, but this is just for Linux based apps.

Im using LibGit2Sharp ti run the `Repository.Clone` function. I've tried mapping a network drive on my Azure Webjob, but I get an "Access Denied"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create azure web app, if you choose option of `Publish` is `Code`, like below. It don't support `net use` command. These webapp are running in standard sandbox env.

[image]

[image]

## Solution:

***Create your web app like below. `Docker Container` will solve your problem.***

Although the container webapp also runs in the sandbox environment, you can customize many configurations.

[image]

[image]

**In local， I test `net use` command, which is same as windows container app.**

[image]

Comment: Ill try it out @jason pan